# Error running flutter developped app on a physical iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter

I run a Flutter app in debug mode on my iPhone 11 from Xcode but when I unplug the iPhone from the mac, the app doesn't open again. My iPhone software is 14.1 and my Xcode version is 12.1. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the most recent release of flutter (1.22), you need to keep your iPhone plugged in to run your app from the IDE. There is no workaround unfortunately.

It was announced here:

> A restriction disables running debug apps on iOS 14 devices except as part of the debugging process

https://medium.com/flutter/announcing-flutter-1-22-44f146009e5f

Comment: Thank you @bm888

Comment: You are welcome @Miles. If this addressed your question, you can mark it as the correct answer.